# Why does warm water and cold water make different sounds?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, acoustics, water, home-experiment

**Why is there a different sound when pouring water for it being warm or cold?** Pouring cold water makes a higher pitch sound than warm water. The difference is clearly distinguishable.

I was unable to find any reliable explanation. Please help.

Comment: Maybe of interest. https://youtu.be/Ri_4dDvcZeM

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247999/158437

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the different viscosity at cold and warm temperatures. This changes the flow behavior and therefore the splashing. This in return changes the sound you hear while pouring it into a cup or something else. I believe there is information to this available with google or youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Another effect may be related to *density*.

Hotter water has lower density than colder water. The speed of sound tends to be higher in lower density media: think 'Donald Duck voice' when you breather in and out helium gas because the density of helium is lower than that of air.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to viscosity of water have look at the graph below you will see how increase in temperature effect the viscosity, and changes in the viscosity result in difference of pitch of sound. Or you can say speed of sound changes as we boil water because density of medium changes. Which is nothing  but the effects of friction between the molecules of water. 
[image]